# Repo browser in svn "Repository moved permanently to... please relocate"

Tags: svn, repository

In the repo browser when I enter the svn root (http://servername/svn) directory I get this message
"Repository moved permanently to 'http//....' please relocate

There are several projects in this repository and I can access/checkout/update each project but I can't even access the root.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem. A local checkout can update correctly, but commands such as `svn ls http://server.com/svn/project` fail with error 301 relocated whether I have a trailing / or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're not the server admin and that you're relatively new to svn...

You'll need to tell your working copies that the remote repo has moved (see the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/) for info on [how to do this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html)). You'll also need to use the new root for your remote repo browsing.

Comment: Thnx for your reply.
Yep im fairly new to svn... Well my working copy is pointing to the new location already as I have checked it out from the new location. What I am tryng to do is to move a folder along with all the revisions from one project to another... So like from http://servername/svn/proj1/tags to http://servername/svn/proj2/tags. when I use the svn move command I get the same message which is really puzzling.

Comment: OK, from the sounds of it you've actually got two different subversion repos, server/svn/proj1 and server/svn/proj2. If this is the case then as far as I know you're not going to be able to move them across.

Have you tried checking out server/svn - unless there's large amounts of content this might be a faster way to move the folder. It would also establish whether or not you have a single repo.

Comment: If you are trying to move a folder between repos then you might find this: http://nileshbansal.blogspot.com/2006/03/moving-folder-across-svn-repositories.html useful.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Looks like I dont have a single repo which is probably why I was unable to perform simple commands like move. I have decided to move the files anyway and for the revisions I will keep the old repos untouched. once again thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same message because I had a double underline character within one folder name; e. g. SVNPath C:/xampp/my/path/to/the/repo/with/double/__underline/repo-folder

I removed them and it works (remember restarting the webserver)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this also helps anyone.   I found this message can appear if you have a DocumentRoot defined in your vhost.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the root is at http://servername/svn/repositoryname. I think there are some known problems when you have the repository in the root (ie when your URL is what you describe, and the name of the repos is 'svn').

**Edit:** This means there's no level above `/svn/proj1/` as far as Subversion is concerned. It is also impossible to move (with keeping history) items from `/svn/proj1/` to `/svn/proj2/`. I think that you've been too active creating repositories, causing problems when trying to reuse items frome one repository in the other. See [a discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761513/multiple-svn-repositories-or-single-company-repository) about multiple repositories vs a single one, and the [faq entry](http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#multi-merge) on how to merge multiple repositories into one.

You might want to take a look at [externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s04.html) if you want to re-use part of the proj1 repository in the proj2 repository.

Comment: Thnx for your reply.
Well I have multiple projects in the root folder and I can access them ok. What I am trying to do is to move a folder from one project to another and I dont want to loose the revisions either.. So like from http://servername/svn/proj1/tags to http://servername/svn/proj2/tags.
when I use the svn move command I get the same message (repos permanently moved... please relocate) which is really puzzling.

Comment: I think /svn/proj1 and /svn/proj2 are two different repositories. Use `svn info` on both URLs to see the repository GUID. If they are different repositories, you cannot move/copy files between them. A file's history is tracked within a single repository

Comment: Thanks Sander. The repository UUIDs are different. Looks like I ont have different repos. I have decided to move the files anyway and for the revisions I will keep the old repos untouched. once again thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the locaction block specified correctly in your apache config file:

```
<Location /svn>
```

not

```
<Location /svn/>
```

Comment: Actually, mine is working with `<Location /svn/ >` to browse the list of projects with `SVNParentPath /path/to/repositories` and `SVNListParentPath on`. But I still get 301 relocated errors from Tortoise SVN clients.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Apache Configuration and remove/comment the ErrorDocument redirection.
That's all.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old now but for completeness sake; I'm accessing the SVN server by IP address but I received this message after adding a redirect in .htaccess file from a non-www domain to a www domain. So be careful with this.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. Considering that you are not admin of the server, as I am not, I've used the `svn switch --relocate` command with success:

`svn switch --relocate https://my.server.url/svn/projectname https://my.server.url/new.dictory/authscm/username/svn/projectname`

Of course, these two URLs and their relative directories happened to be in my case, but in general lines this solution worked fine for me, i.e., `using switch --relocate` from the old to the new URL.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this with spaces in the SVN url and using `Cornerstone`. Using terminal `svn checkout <url>` did work instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case if was the wrong Proxy settings for Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have duplicate name in svn repo and htdocs/html folder.